# Javascript: Replace Date's full day name and full month name with 3 letters. Tuesday > Tue

Tags: javascript

I have a simple snippet which prints full day, month, day of month, hour and minute.

Here is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/raNms/

I want to change where

```
Monday > Mon
Tuesday > Tue
...
```

and months:

```
January > Jan
February > Feb
...
```

Can it be done before appending to body? I don't want to replace the appended text but to print it correctly from the beginning.

The JavaScript:

```
var now= new Date(),
    ampm= 'am',
    h= now.getHours(),
    m= now.getMinutes(),
    s= now.getSeconds();
    if(h>= 12){
        if(h>12)h-= 12;
        ampm= 'pm';
    }
    if(h<10) h= '0'+h;
    if(m<10) m= '0'+m;
    var time = now.toLocaleDateString()+' '+h+':'+m+' '+ampm

   $('body').html(time);
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to put the code here, since jsfiddle tends to be unreliable. I've edited it in.

Comment: You might want to look at the [datejs](http://www.datejs.com) library, which has a `toString()` method that acts as a templating system for dates.

Comment: Thanks Pointy for the edit. I am on the go on a mobile device so its a little bit hard. I am aware of datejs library but when it comes to just a line of code, its useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this:

```
var txt = now.toLocaleDateString().replace(/\b[a-z]+\b/gi,function($0){return $0.substring(0,3)});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/raNms/1/

Comment: Found this the most easy way I guess

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great way of doing it: http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/getting_current_time_using_javascript.php3

Here is what your code looks like with the changes:

Output:

```
Sat, Jan 7 2012 04:21 pm
```

Code:

```
var now= new Date(),
    ampm= 'am',
    h= now.getHours(),
    m= now.getMinutes(),
    s= now.getSeconds();
    if(h>= 12){
        if(h>12)h-= 12;
        ampm= 'pm';
    }
    if(h<10) h= '0'+h;
    if(m<10) m= '0'+m;


var weekdayNames = new Array("Sun", "Mon", "Tuey",
"Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat");

var monthNames = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", 
"Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", 
"Oct", "Nov", "Dec");

    //var dateString = now.toLocaleDateString();
    var weekday = weekdayNames[now.getDay()];
    var month = monthNames[now.getMonth()];
    var dateString = weekday + ', ' + month + ' ' + now.getDate() + ' ' + now.getFullYear();
    var time = dateString +' '+h+':'+m+' '+ampm

   $('body').html(time);
```

I also created a jsFiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/luisperezphd/raNms/2/

Comment: Thank you. Works really great and is a great example for using it many times. In my case though its for a lil script I will be using myself thus I've chosen Ivan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

A easy way:

```
    var now= new Date(),
    ampm= 'am',
    h= now.getHours(),
    m= now.getMinutes(),
    s= now.getSeconds();
    if(h>= 12){
        if(h>12)h-= 12;
        ampm= 'pm';
    }
    if(h<10) h= '0'+h;
    if(m<10) m= '0'+m;
    t = now.toLocaleDateString();
    var time = t.split(',')[0].substring(0,3) + ', ' +
               t.split(',')[1].substring(1,4) + ' ' + 
               t.split(',')[1].split(' ')[2] +
               t.split(',')[2] + ', ' +
               ' '+h+':'+m+' '+ampm

   $('body').html(time);
```

Output:

```
Sat, Jan 07 2012, 10:20 pm
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a suitable library, such as [Globalize.js](https://github.com/jquery/globalize). Ad hoc code for dealing with things like this takes more work, tends to be less reliable, and means a burden when you need to modify your software.

Example:

```
Globalize.format(today,'ddd, MMM d, yyyy') + ' ' + Globalize.format(today,'T')
```

Produces e.g.

```
Sat, Jan 7, 2012 11:32:21 PM
```

You can tune the appearance by modifying the formatting strings.

Notice that `toLocaleString` is by definition system-dependent, so it may produce weekday names in any language (or not at all). Here’s what your code produces in my environment on one browser:
“7. tammikuuta 2012 11:26 pm”.